# ¿Cómo saber si existe un fichero en Java?

Tags: java

Quiero saber como saber si dada un ruta puedo saber si un fichero existe o no en Java. ¿Existe alguna forma utilizando la clase `File` o similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en efecto, la clase `java.io.File` tiene dicha función, que se llama `exists()`

para usarla, tienes que instanciar un objecto de la clase File

```
File af = new File(filename);
```

e invocarla

```
if (af.exists()) { 
  // etcétera   
}
```

ahora bien, si lo que quieres es cerciorarte de que realmente sea un fichero, será mejor que uses la función `.isFile()`

```
if (af.isFile()) ...
```

porque `.exists()` devuelve verdadero también cuando es una directorio, o un enlace simbólico u otros objetos del sistema de archivos.

Answer (score 2):

Por nuestro bien, cuando estamos trabajando con ficheros, deberíamos de validar la existencia o no del fichero o directorio con el que vamos a trabajar. Ahora, que hay mucho lanzado en esta vida, que puede pensar que que más da.

Claro, que si instanciamos la clase File, en Java, con un fichero que no existe y por ejemplo, intentamos recuperar el tamaño del mismo, no nos vamos a llevar ninguna desagradable sorpresa de que salte una excepción.

```
String sFichero = "c:\misficheros\fichero.txt";
File fichero = new File(sFichero);

if (fichero.exists())
   System.out.println("El fichero " + sFichero + " existe");
else
   System.out.println("Pues va a ser que no");
```

Answer (score 0):

seria esto amigo

```
       File Arch=new File(url);
        if(Arch.exists()){
            //el archivo existe
        }
```